# What happened with the (i) icon for console.info()?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I noticed that console.info() no longer shows an (i) icon to the left of the line. There is no difference between console.info() and console.log().

On 49.0.2623.112 (on XP) it looks like this:

[image: Output from console.info()]

My current version is  64.0.3282.140  but I think the icon has been gone for a while.

Is there some setting to get the icon back?

Comment: https://crbug.com/714235

Comment: Thanks. I feared it was a "feature" and sadly I was right.

Answer (score 3):

Josh Lee's link suggest the following workaround:

```
console.log("%ci%c Hello", "color: white; background: blue;", "");
```

Elaborating on that, one can have

```
function logInfo(text, bgColor, color) {
    console.log(`%c${text}`, `color: ${color}; background: ${bgColor};`);
}
    
logInfo('test 1', 'orange', 'black');
logInfo('test 2', 'white', 'green');
logInfo('test 3', 'green', 'white');
```

This actually gives us more flexibility - and one can customize his own special output types.

In a short: would chrome not have removed the feature, I would not learn about this :)

Answer (score 2):

As already specified by Josh Lee, it sadly got removed.
I tried replicating the behavior.

Take a look at it: https://github.com/evertdespiegeleer/console.info

Comment: Nice. Will try it.